# best way to get an integer from string without using regex

Tags: python, string, int

I would like to get some integers from a string (the 3rd one). Preferable without using regex.

I saw a lot of stuff.

my string:

```
xp = '93% (9774/10500)'
```

So i would like the code to return a list with integers from a string. So the desired output would be: `[93, 9774, 10500]`

Some stuff like this doesn't work:

```
>>> new = [int(s) for s in xp.split() if s.isdigit()]
>>> print new
[]
>>> int(filter(str.isdigit, xp))
93977410500
```

Comment: Are we talking about *any string*, or a string that is formatted exactly like in your example `xp` variable?

Comment: The string will be the same. Of course it could also be 100% or 10057/5947. The more versitale the better

Comment: The use `split("%")` and `split("/")` and trim away the parentheses and you should be set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the problem is that you have to split on different chars, you can first replace everything that's not a digit by a space then split, a one-liner would be :

```
 xp = '93% (9774/10500)'
 ''.join([ x if x.isdigit() else ' ' for x in xp ]).split() # ['93', '9774', '10500']
```

Comment: You could even drop the list (i.e. the `[`..`]`) and pass a generator expression straight to `join()`.

Comment: that's actually elegant

Comment: smart and elegant

Comment: Really clever! I like it.

Comment: but it's not an answer, why author said that he want a list of numbers not a strings.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe You actually shouldn't do that as `join()` builds a list in the background anyways, it's actually faster to just use a list comprehension as opposed to a generator.

Comment: @SethMichaelLarson: That's an implementation detail (a reasonable alternate implementation could avoid `list`ifying); admittedly, on Py2, the time cost of a genexpr here is significantly higher than a listcomp (~40% higher runtime, where it's closer to 25% on Py3), but it's balanced by other issues (in Py2, listcomps leak iteration variables into surrounding scope, instead of operating as separately scoped closures, which is part of why they run faster, avoiding extra closure and stack frame setup and teardown). Mostly a personal preference here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Don't really understand how "not leaking iter variables" is a justifiable reason for a slower program. Those are free cycles! Have you ever "run out" of variable names?

Comment: @SethMichaelLarson: The problem is that it overwrites those variables. If you never use `x` outside the listcomp, then no problem (more local variables hardly matters, as you say). But if you have, say, `x = 10`, `[x for x in range(5)]`, and then print `x`, `x` is now `4`, not `10`, even outside the listcomp. It causes headaches (Py3 made listcomps use closures with nested scope for that reason, along with simplifying implementation of comprehensions in general a bit). If you're really concerned about performance, you'd use [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39371143/364696) anyway.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Couldn't that be solved by prefixing with _ and using variable names that mean something? And in Python 3 where there still exists a speed-up but no problem like you mentioned? I'm just having trouble accepting your justification for not using listcomp in almost all instances.

Comment: @SethMichaelLarson: "Solving it" by being extra careful with variable names is not a real solution; maintainers can easily accidentally undo your workaround without understanding it. Besides, I didn't say genexprs should be preferred for `join`, just that there are reasons to not be religious about it (genexpr is better in cases where you're iterating it without building a `list`, but obviously if you'll build a `list` anyway, there's no gain). Speed differences on Py3 are a cost of saving/restoring generator state per-item, often worth it for the iteration case, just not for `list`ifying.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex (sorry!) to split the string by a non-digit, then filter on digits (can have empty fields) and convert to int.

```
import re

xp = '93% (9774/10500)'

print([int(x) for x in filter(str.isdigit,re.split("\D+",xp))])
```

result:

```
[93, 9774, 10500]
```

Comment: could you explain the \D+

Comment: `\D` is any non-digit character, `+` means one or more.

Comment: learnt `\D` yesterday. I was just one day ahead of you :) Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Py2, using `str`, it looks like you don't need to consider the full Unicode range; since you're doing this more than once, you can slightly improve on [polku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39369911/364696) using `str.translate`:

```
# Create a translation table once, up front, that replaces non-digits with 
import string
nondigits = ''.join(c for c in map(chr, range(256)) if not c.isdigit())
nondigit_to_space_table = string.maketrans(nondigits, ' ' * len(nondigits))

# Then, when you need to extract integers use the table to efficiently translate
# at C layer in a single function call:
xp = '93% (9774/10500)'
intstrs = xp.translate(nondigit_to_space_table).split() # ['93', '9774', 10500]

myints = map(int, intstrs)  # Wrap in `list` constructor on Py3
```

Performance-wise, for the test string on my 64 bit Linux 2.7 build, using `translate` takes about 374 nanoseconds to run, vs. 2.76 microseconds for the listcomp and `join` solution; the listcomp+`join` takes >7x longer. For larger strings (where the fixed overhead is trivial compared to the actual work), the listcomp+`join` solution takes closer to 20x longer.

Main advantage to polku's solution is that it requires no changes on Py3 (on which it should seamlessly support non-ASCII strings), where `str.translate` builds the translation table a different way there (`str.translate`) and it would be impractical to make a translation table that handled all non-digits in the whole Unicode space.

Answer (score -1):

Since the *format is fixed*, you can use consecutive `split()`.
It's not very pretty, or general, but sometimes the direct and "stupid" solution is not so bad:

```
a, b = xp.split("%")
x = int(a)
y = int(b.split("/")[0].strip()[1:])
z = int(b.split("/")[1].strip()[:-1])
print(x, y, z) # prints "93 9774 10500"
```

**Edit**: Clarified that the poster specifically said that his format is **fixed**. This solution is not very pretty, but it does what it's supposed to.